# How to convert a bar legend to line legend in chart.js 2.7.2?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, legend, legend-properties

I am trying to create a line graph using chart.js v2.7.2 and here is what it looks like:
[image]

```js
const labels = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
];
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First dataset',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
  }]
};


const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
};

const myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
  );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

    
<body>
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code on JS Bin: https://jsbin.com/kegedewiyi/edit?html,js,output

I want the legend to be converted to a line instead of a bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I just had to use [`pointStyle`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.3.1/samples/legend/point-style.html).

Here is the new chart image:

[image]

Here is the code:

```js
const labels = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
];
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First dataset',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
    pointStyle: "line",
  }]
};


const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        usePointStyle: true,
      }
    },
  }
};

const myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
  );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>


<body>
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code on JS Bin: https://jsbin.com/lolajokujo/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I have provided the code for your reference .Refer link for more understanding
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.7.3/configuration/legend.html
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

```js
const labels = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
];
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First dataset',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
  }]
};


const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
options: {
    legend: {
        display: true,
        labels: {
            fontColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
        }
    }
}
};

const myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
  );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

    
<body>
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```